# AWS Transit Gatway to connect multiple VPC in a region (NEW AWS Service )

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am trying to write a CloudFormation template to deploy a Transit Gateway and want to connect my all VPC of a region to that Gateway. I have written a template but not able to set the GatewayRoutetable routing

```
TransitGateway:
Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGateway"
Properties:
  AmazonSideAsn: 65000
  Description: "TGW Route Integration "
  AutoAcceptSharedAttachments: "disable"
  DefaultRouteTableAssociation: "enable"
  DnsSupport: "enable"
  VpnEcmpSupport: "enable"
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: !Join ["-", ["ath", !Ref 'Env', "transit", "gateway", !Ref 'AWS::Region']]
    - Key: Env
      Value: !Ref 'Env'
    - Key: Region
      Value: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
   TransitGatewayAttachment:
   Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayAttachment"
   Properties:
     SubnetIds:
      - !Ref SubnetPublic1
    - !Ref SubnetPublic2
      - !Ref SubnetWorker1
    - !Ref SubnetWorker2
    TransitGatewayId: !Ref TransitGateway
    VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

   TransitGatewayRouteTable:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRouteTable"
    Properties:
     Tags:
       - Key: Name
         Value: !Join ["-", ["ath", !Ref 'Env', "RouteTable", "TransitGateway", !Ref 'AWS::Region']]
      - Key: Env
        Value: !Ref 'Env'
      - Key: Region
        Value: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
  TransitGatewayId: !Ref TransitGateway
   TransitGatewayRouting:
   Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRoute"
    Properties:
    Blackhole: true
    DestinationCidrBlock:
    TransitGatewayAttachmentId: !Ref TransitGatewayAttachment
    TransitGatewayRouteTableId: !Ref TransitGateway

     TransitGatewayRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRouteTableAssociation"
      Properties:
      TransitGatewayAttachmentId: !Ref TransitGatewayAttachment
      TransitGatewayRouteTableId: !Ref TransitGatewayRouteTable

    TransitGatewayRouteTablePropagation:
     Type: "AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRouteTablePropagation"
     Properties:
     TransitGatewayAttachmentId: !Ref TransitGatewayAttachment
     TransitGatewayRouteTableId: !Ref TransitGatewayRouteTable
```

Now I am able to deploy my Transit Gateway also able to attach it to a VPC  able to create a route table but, my problem is that when I come to TransitGatewayRouting it prompt me to enter CIDRdestination . I am confused about it referring to which CIDR Destination and what should I mention to get it working as of now as it does not keep the routing for the VPC.

And another part of question is how would I manage to code so that even in future if there is a new VPC get created in same region I'll able to connect that VPC to this very same transit gateway.

Comment: Interesting article that also mentions the lack of CloudFormation support for certain TGW functionality at this time: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/02/14/aws-site-to-site-vpn-and-transit-gateway/